# Flutterengine: App crashes after entering release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-engine

Frnds... I'm facing a severe issue in release mode after I build an app... It crashes after launching the app... I got the following error in the console as "Tried to send viewport metrics from Android to Flutter but this FlutterView was not attached to a FlutterEngine." Anybody could give solve it would be help

In debug mode... It is working just fine....

While in release mode it forces the app to close while launching.

Sometimes I will not getting any errors... But the app still crashes. While I made it run in debug flutterengine renders its view after release mode this engine does not render it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your main function -

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

So finally your main function should like this -

```
void main() {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I disabled the R8 option in the app/build.Gradle file..because it is shrinking my code while I build the app. so I run my command as flutter build apk --no-shrink..Then it works well without app crashes.